Reproducing Ómar Rayo's "Fresh Fog" Painting
Ómar Rayo
Ómar Rayo (1928 - 2010) was a Colombian painter best known for his
op-art paintings. He completed his first drawing studies at an
academy in Buenos Aires. In 1960 he received a Guggenheim scholarship
and moved to New York, where he would settle definitively years later
in 1976 and where his work would achieve full international
recognition.

Ómar Rayo, Xaquima, 1972
Rayo's compositions present series of ribbons that come and go over
each other, forming patterns that produce striking optical effects.
The result is a geometric labyrinth of simulated
three-dimensionality, sometimes made in black and white and other
times in bright colors. His mathematical rigor and precision
contribute to the impression of infinity that his works produce.

Ómar Rayo, Muy Muiname II, 1994
In 1981 Rayo established the Rayo Museum of Latin American Drawing
and Engraving in his native town of Roldanillo, Colombia. Many of
Rayo's works are on display, in addition to five hundred works by different
Latin American artists who were part of his personal collection.
Fresh Fog

Ómar Rayo, Fresh Fog, 1966
I was able to reproduce the patterns of Fresh Fog, but don't know how to create the shadowy effects to simulate three-dimensionality.
rect = {
   GrayLevel[1], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}],
   GrayLevel[0], Rectangle[{0, 1}, {3, 2}],
   GrayLevel[1], Rectangle[{0, 2}, {3, 3}]};

m[t_, r_] := Rotate[Translate[rect, {t, 0}], r]

p = Pi/2;


a =
  {m[0, p], m[3, 0], m[6, 0], m[9, p], m[12, 0], m[15, p],
   m[18, p], m[21, 0], m[24, p], m[27, 0], m[30, 0], m[33, p]};

b = a /. {m[a_, p] :> m[a, 0], m[a_, 0] :> m[a, p]};

Graphics /@ {a, b} // Column


c =
  {Translate[a, {0, 0}],  Translate[b, {0, 3}],  Translate[b, {0, 6}],
   Translate[a, {0, 9}],  Translate[a, {0, 12}], Translate[b, {0, 15}],
   Translate[a, {0, 18}], Translate[b, {0, 21}], Translate[b, {0, 24}],
   Translate[a, {0, 27}], Translate[b, {0, 30}], Translate[a, {0, 33}]};


Graphics[{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.7]], Rotate[c, 45 Degree]},
 Axes -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{6, 24}, {6, 24}}]


Question
How can we add the shadowy three-dimensional effects?

Using a "dirty" gradient.
c = 667;
ra = Raster[
   Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2] Boole[4 < y <= c || 2*c < y < 3 c - 3] + 
     RandomReal[{-0.06, 0.06}], {x, -1, 1, .001}, {y, 667*3}]];
gra = {Translate[ra, {0, -3} c], Translate[ra, {9, -3} c], 
   Translate[ra, {0, -12} c], Translate[Rotate[ra, Pi/2], {0, -6} c], 
   Translate[Rotate[ra, Pi/2], {0, -9} c], 
   Translate[Scale[ra, {1, 2}], {3, -15/2} c], 
   Translate[Scale[ra, {1, 2}], {6, -15/2} c], 
   Translate[Rotate[Scale[ra, {1, 2}], Pi/2], {9/2, -3} c]};
Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[gra, RotationTransform[#]] & /@ 
   Table[Pi/4 n, {n, 1, 7, 2}]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> 5300]



Without PlotRange -> 5300:

Applying ImageEffect[%, "Sepia"] on the first image:


It is amazing that such 3D result can be achieved with 2D graphics!

3D plotting might be an option:
Clear["Global`*"]
plotOptions = { Mesh -> 2
   , MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, v]}
   , MeshShading -> {RGBColor[{.96, .94, .90}], GrayLevel[.3]}
   , BoundaryStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.3], Thickness[.002]]
   , PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 3
   , Axes -> True, Boxed -> False};

plotA[factor_, size_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{factor Cos[theta], Sin[theta], z}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {z, 0, size}
  , Evaluate@plotOptions]
plotB[factor_, size_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{z, Sin[theta], factor Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {z, 0, size}
  , Evaluate@plotOptions]

{p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]} = {First@plotA[1.5, 3], 
   Translate[First@plotA[3, 3], {1.5, 0, 0}], 
   Translate[First@plotB[1.5, 3], {-1.5, 0, 1.5}], Point[{0, 0, 0}]};

a = MapThread[
     Translate[#1, {#2, 0, 0}] &, {p /@ {1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1}
    , Table[i, {i, 0, 33, 3}]}];
b = MapThread[
     Translate[#1, {#2, 0, 0}] &, {p /@ {3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1}
    , Table[i, {i, 0, 33, 3}]}];
c = MapThread[
     Translate[#1, {0, 0,  #2}] &, {{a, b, b, a, a , b, a, b, b, a, b, a}
    , Table[i, {i, 0, 33, 3}]}];

Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[{DirectionalLight[White, {1, 1, 1}], 
   c}, {{RotationMatrix[45 °, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 0, 1}}}]
 , Lighting -> "ThreePoint"
 , ViewPoint -> {.15, 15, 0}
 , Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.1]
 , PlotRange -> {{19, 37}, {0, 1}, {-11, 7} }
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 ]



I'd probably try something like the following, but it needs more tweaking to get full fidelity.
shading = LinearGradientImage[{Top, Bottom} -> {GrayLevel[.7], White, White, White, GrayLevel[.7]}, {200, 200}]


offwhite = RGBColor[{.99, .98, .96}];
band = ImageResize[Image[{{offwhite, Black, offwhite}}], {200, 200}]


squareCell[0] = ImageMultiply[band, shading]


squareCell[1] = ImageRotate[squareCell[0]]


pattern = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
ImageAssemble[Map[squareCell, pattern, {-1}]]




We try to do the more general cases.

The main idea is that these ribbons are crossing up and down,so we use Mod similar with MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], Frame -> False] to get such pattern.

That is we needs two types of ribbons beltX and beltY.


Clear["Global`*"];
beltX[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := 
  Table[{{LinearGradientFilling[{Gray, 
       Splice@ConstantArray[White, x2 - x1 + 1], Gray}, Right], 
     Rectangle @@ {{x1, y}, {x2, y + 1}}}, {Black, 
     Rectangle @@ {{x1, y + 1/3}, {x2, y + 2/3}}}}, {y, 
    Range[y1, y2 - 1]}];
(*beltX[{1,2},{5,8}]//Graphics*)
beltY[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := 
  Table[{{LinearGradientFilling[{Gray, 
       Splice@ConstantArray[White, y2 - y1 + 1], Gray}, Top], 
     Rectangle @@ {{x, y1}, {x + 1, y2}}}, {Black, 
     Rectangle @@ {{x + 1/3, y1}, {x + 2/3, y2}}}}, {x, 
    Range[x1, x2 - 1]}];
(*beltY[{1,2},{5,8}]//Graphics*)
xlist = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 15];
ylist = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 17];
xpartitions = Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, xlist], 2, 1];
ypartitions = Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, ylist], 2, 1];
g = Graphics[
  Table[If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 1, 
    beltX[xpartitions[[i]], ypartitions[[j]]], 
    beltY[xpartitions[[i]], ypartitions[[j]]]], {i, 1, 
    Length@xpartitions}, {j, 1, Length@ypartitions}], 
  ImageSize -> Large]



If we set

xlist = {2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1};
ylist = {2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};

and the filling direction θX = 45 Degree;θY = 135 Degree; and rotate the picture, we can get the original picture.
Clear["Global`*"];
θX = 45   Degree;
θY = 135   Degree;
beltX[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := 
  Table[{{LinearGradientFilling[{Black, 
       Splice@ConstantArray[White, x2 - x1], Black}, θX], 
     Rectangle @@ {{x1, y}, {x2, y + 1}}}, {Black, 
     Rectangle @@ {{x1, y + 1/3}, {x2, y + 2/3}}}}, {y, 
    Range[y1, y2 - 1]}];
beltY[{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}] := 
  Table[{{LinearGradientFilling[{Black, 
       Splice@ConstantArray[White, y2 - y1], Black}, θY], 
     Rectangle @@ {{x, y1}, {x + 1, y2}}}, {Black, 
     Rectangle @@ {{x + 1/3, y1}, {x + 2/3, y2}}}}, {x, 
    Range[x1, x2 - 1]}];
xlist = {2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1};
ylist = {2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};
xpartitions = Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, xlist], 2, 1];
ypartitions = Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, ylist], 2, 1];
g = Graphics[
  Rotate[#, π/4] &@
   Table[If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 1, 
     beltX[xpartitions[[i]], ypartitions[[j]]], 
     beltY[xpartitions[[i]], ypartitions[[j]]]], {i, 1, 
     Length@xpartitions}, {j, 1, Length@ypartitions}], 
  PlotRange -> {{3, 9}, {3, 9}}]


